# How to embed more than 2 aggregations in elastic?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm making an application that allows users to create reports on customers data, the user is able to add 0 or more grouping fields.

I'm using elastic 2.2.0, so if the user wants to group by day, then by age and then by sex the program sends the following query to elastic:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "group_a": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "transactionDate",
        "interval": "day"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "group_b": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "age"
          }
        },
        "aggs": {
          "group_c": {
            "terms": {
              "field": "sex"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "search_parse_exception",
        "reason": "Could not find aggregator type [group_c] in [aggs]",
        "line": 15,
        "col": 11
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to nest `group_c` into `group_b`, you should use this json:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "group_a": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "transactionDate",
        "interval": "day"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "group_b": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "age"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "group_c": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "sex"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that you were defining `group_c` outside of `group_b`, that was the error.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have an extra `aggs` in there. Try removing the `aggs` surrounding the `group_c` section.

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "group_a": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "transactionDate",
        "interval": "day"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "group_b": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "age"
          }
        },
        "group_c": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "sex"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is how the [ES documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html) suggests to write the query (`aggregation_name_1`, `aggregation_name_2`):

```
"aggregations" : {
    "<aggregation_name_1>" : {
        "<aggregation_type>" : {
            <aggregation_body>
        }
        [,"meta" : {  [<meta_data_body>] } ]?
        [,"aggregations" : { [<sub_aggregation>]+ } ]?
    }
    [,"<aggregation_name_2>" : { ... } ]*
}
```

Comment: That works! I had to make some minor changes to your JSON, because it has an extra comma.

Comment: Thank, you're right. I missed that comma when writing the code. Also, if you needed `group_c` inside `group_b`, Federico Peralta Schaffner answer does exactly that. Mine was a bit more general

Answer (score 0):

See the example that i did with my data, i used filters aggregation

```
curl -XGET "http://192.168.99.100:9200/loja/produtos/_search" -d'
{
  "aggs" : {
    "messages" : {
      "filters" : {
        "filters" : {
          "names" :   { "term" : { "nome" : "produto"   }},
          "descriptions" : { "term" : { "description" : "short" }}
        }
      },
      "aggs" : {
        "sumPeso" : {
           "sum" : {
               "field" : "peso" 
           } 
        },
        "sumValor": {
           "sum" : {
               "field" : "valor" 
           } 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

If you dont understand please ask me